# error can't String to boolean when trying to use variable as String

Tags: java, types

i'm trying to make a simple code and this point in the code generates an error in the script saying String can't be used as boolean even though i'm not using it as boolean

```
String wc = Mt.input("asks for input") /*i have a class called Mt that basically just makes writing lines and asking for input easier*/ 
if (wc = "a possible input for wc") {//error occurs here
    Mt.s("words");
    Mt.input("");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean

    at Main.main(Main.java:20)//line of if statement in full code
```

Comment: 1. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality. 2. Use `compare()` for Strings and all other objects

Comment: in addition to above, comparing Strings with `==` is true only when both Strings points to the same memory location. Getting String from any input will have different memory location than the hardcoded one. Use `"a possible inut for wc".equals(wc)` instead.